# What is meaning of underscore in front of function in PAWN?

Tags: pawn

In php underscore ("_") it's declaration of private/protected function but i didn't found anything about it in PAWN. Does it have any meaning in PAWN?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It depends.

In function name doesn't mean anything so `_hello` just means that the function is named `_hello`. (Then, if you prefer, you can read all function which starts with an underscore as function that must not be called in public code. But PAWN doesn't force you)

If you mean the underscore in the parameters when you call a function, then it means "Use the default value" so if you have

```
stock hello(num = 5) { }
```

then you can do `hello(_)` and `hello` will be called with `num` with `5` (default value).

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Now i have confirmation of my conjectures.

Comment: Also `_:` means a tagless cell.